# request for member [FUNCTION NAME] in [OBJ NAME], which is of non class type [CLASS NAME]

Tags: c++

I'm getting the compile error as mentioned in the heading for the code below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class Test
{
    std::string name;
    public:
    Test() {name = "rr";}
    Test(std::string input) {name = input;}

    std::string PrintName() { return name; }
};

int main()
{
    const char* myname = "rr";
    Test t1(std::string(myname));
    cout << t1.PrintName() << endl;
}
```

Please help

Comment: [Most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)?

Comment: @DevSolar - Yup. A function taking a `std::string` and returning a `Test`

Comment: @Deepak: replace "Test t1(std::string(myname));" with "Test t1(myname);" to solve